# Facebook app - don't request permission to get users data

Tags: php, facebook

I've created a simple Facebook app that doesn't need any data/info from users. When I try to view the app on Facebook, it's requesting permission to access my personal info.

I want the app to display without this request, for both logged in and not logged in users.

What's the code to do this?

Edit with more info:

I have a working Facebook app which I want to leave alone, I've duplicated the apps code and created a new app through the Facebook dev area. I've changed the relevant App ID, API ID and Secrets throughout the code. The original app works without any permission needed, but my duplicated version for some reason requests permission.

Comment: I think you just do HTTP POST same way you would do HTTP GET and then it won't require login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution is to create the app in the developers area, do all the settings to an iframe and create the application path to your website. Now in your website remove all the PHP code related to FACEBOOK GRAPH API and let it be a simple website that is independent of facebook. This will make what you want.

Comment: If the asker is satisfied with the answer, then please mark it as correct for other people's future reference.